# One-way function with conditions as inputs

Tags: encryption, authentication, cryptography, hash

I need to write a one-way function, with some conditions as inputs, for example:

```
if ((a==b && c==2 ) || (c > 10000))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

The result would only be 2 values (e.g., 0 or 1).

The key point is, by looking at the function and the result, we cannot figure out what the conditions (e.g., `(if ((a==b && c==2 ) || (c > 10000)))` ) are. Just like a hash function.

Is there any function (tricks) to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to make your own hash algorithm then?

Comment: Just curious about whether there are existing solutions. If no, yes.

Comment: Yes, they're called hashing algorithms. I still don't understand your question.

Comment: The hashing is like you give a value, then get a result. The problem is that, if using a rainbow table, you can easily numerate all the simple numbers like 1,2,3,...  Here what I need is those conditions, that cannot be simply figured out using rainbow tables.

Comment: This looks like a so-called "XY problem". What is it, exactly, that you're trying to accomplish? What is your scenario, your use case?

Comment: Regardless of the XY problem, I'm completely not sure what is being asked.  For instance, you do not give context to a, b, or c. Are they relevant to the outcome? Could they be seeds or salts for a hashing algorithm?

Comment: The scenario is: We want to release patches for 0-day vulnerabilities by checking/validating function arguments (e.g., out of range, etc.). However, we do not want malicious parties to know what the vulnerability is. So we want to design a mechanism to patch the vulnerable program, but not leak the vulnerability details to the public.

Comment: So, what you're really after is [input-hiding obfuscation](http://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2014/83490180/83490180.pdf) against auxiliary input that's known to the obfuscator. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Any examples or materials for how to construct such a function? I tried to read the paper but can hardly understand the notations and terms.

Comment: No, and I suspect there's probably no such way. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Why there is probably no such way? In the paper, does the author prove that it is impossible?

Comment: I'm imagining conditions of the form [[starts with a secret and next few bits match a look-up table] or [is an encryption of that lookup table]], where the auxiliary information is an [encryption](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22fully+homomorphic+encryption%22&t=hh&ia=web) of the secret prefix. ​ ​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like, where you encode all the conditions in a hash, that is carefully constructed to return specific bits at certain positions. Note that the hash will output a random value, so you would yourself need to bruteforce some of the constants to get the output you want:

```
if chr(sha512((length(c) > 1000) + "764065445" + b + md5(b.substr(0,10))).substring(15,1)) % 64 then (repeat as many times as neccessary to pick out bits)
```

BUT: This also means you have to accept some false positives, eg where input is rejected even if this does not result in a vulnerability being exploited.

Here, the attacker of course will be able to see the first condition, that length of c either needs to be above or below 1000. But here, the 10 first characters of b, need to result in a unknown md5 hash, that combined with the length of c being either above or under 1000, and result of b, will result in specific bits of a sha512 hash being 1 or 0.

Picking out more bits of the sha512 hash will make false positives less likely, but will also increase the possibility of finding the vulnerability by using rainbow tables.

By only picking out so many bits neccessary to reduce false positives to a minimum, attempting to brute-force the hash or use rainbow tables, will just result in a unlimited number of results.

This is similiar to vanitygen to bitcoin, where you bruteforce out some constant to get certain bits of the hash you want. Note that you DONT test for the full sha512 hash, you only test for certain bits to be true or false.

Comment: Is there any solution for zero false positive? False negative is tolerable as long as the malicious inputs are hard to guess.

Comment: No. Because, if you have false negatives, it means that any input to the hash function that would evaluate to true, would be a successful malicious input. You need to have false positives for the malicious inputs to be hard to guess. The thing is that these false positives could still be constructed so these would be very unnatural to the application in question.

Comment: Could you clarify what `if chr(sha512((length(c) > 1000) + "764065445" + b + md5(b.substr(0,10))).substring(15,1)) % 64 then (repeat as many times as neccessary to pick out bits)` means? Like using Python. I'm confused with the conversion of string, number and bit.

Comment: It was a bit pseudocode just so you understand the idea. Here, the idea was that you take the integer ASCII value, of a specific character inside the sha512 hash, of the inputs, and mod() that, so you get the value of a specific bit. So you pick up a single bit out of the whole sha512 hash. However, a single bit would give about 45% false positives, so here you would need to pick out more bits to get a more confident result. And here I mean that the value "764065445" is a value that you bruteforce a little bit, until certain bits, you wish, in the sha512 hash is true. Think like vanitygen

Comment: What does `` bruteforce "764065445" '' mean? I tried to get an explanation of the algorithm used in Vanitygen, but all the materials only talk about the usage of it, like https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=25804.0

Comment: Assume you have 4 inputs, that should be able to be tested for. By "bruteforcing", I mean you begin with "1", "2", "3" etc until you, by software, finds a couple of bits in the hash that is equal for all 4 inputs. Note that I DONT say you should bruteforce the whole hash, just a portion of it. Another similiar scheme you can look at, is Hashcash. Basically, you bruteforce a input until you get some bits in output you WANT. Then you statically code this input in the patch. This will lead to a function that can secrely test for a vulnerability without giving out the vulnerability.

Comment: If range comparison, do I have to use it as a plaintext, such as the bool result of c>10000 (or maybe use range hash, or encode the 10000?) ?  Also, since an integer has a certain range, can this approach be simply bruteforced by enumerating all the numbers?

Comment: Best is to use the integer result (1=true, 0=false). Yes, the attacker will know there is a boundary at 10000 but since its part of the hash input, the attacker wont know if he should be under 10000 or over 10000. Here, you can also vary, for example use c<10000 but calculating the hash with a 0 as input in this place instead of 1.